# Where is the file loaded while using addFile of SparkFiles, Is it the Cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

The definition I could find is "PySpark
SparkFiles is used to load our files on the Apache Spark application". And this does not clarify that where exactly is the file loaded.

Please clarify this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.addFile.html) says:

> Add a file to be downloaded with this Spark job on every node.

To my understanding, the file will be available on every executor then.